# Testing for differences, would I use ANOVA?

Tags: anova, z-test, statistical-significance

I have four age groups all measuring different heights: How would I test for difference between the groups at 0.01 level of significance? Would I use ANOVA?

Also - how could I establish which group is different from the others at the 0.01 level of significance?

Comment: Do you have any reason not to use ANOVA? This appears so natural for it that it could be textbook. If ANOVA does find differences, then use Tukey to find which pairs of groups have significant differences.

Comment: @NickSabbe, that seems sufficient to me to be an answer in this circumstance. I could not find a duplicate - I would have thought something similar was already asked and answered on the site (most of the popular questions the ANOVA tag are much more advanced questions).

Comment: Is the Tukey test essentially multiple t-tests ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A grouping variable (age group) potentially inducing differences in a continuous variable (height) that may be reasonably expected to be normally distributed in each group (and depending on some more investigation: maybe even with the same variance in each group): this is boilerplate ANOVA.

After you've found differences, you can use Tukey to find which pairs of groups differ significantly. Tukey's method is akin to t-tests between each of the groups, but the significance level used for each of those t-tests is not the original 0.01: you need to be *more* certain for each of the individual tests to be able to make a statement about *all of them at once*. This is just one of many possible multiple testing corrections, but it is a popular and well working one for (oneway) ANOVA (and not as needlessly conservative as Bonferroni).